# ¿Por que se genera el error "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\inicio-sesion.php"

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este problema al intentar ingresar con un inicio de sesion, las tablas se llaman "administradores" y "usuarios" y en ambas tablas las columnas se llaman "usuario" y "contrasena". se supone que segun el tipo de usuario deberia de llevar a una direccion distinta, en el caso del admin seria a "admin.php" que se encuentra en una carpeta llamada "admin" y el usuario normal deberia dirigirse a "usuarios.php" en la carpeta "usuarios".

ya las tablas tienen los usuarios y contraseña que deberian iniciar la sesion pero sigue dando el error

```
<?php

include './conexion.php';

$usuario=$_POST["usuario"];
$contrasena=$_POST["contrasena"];

$admin = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contrasena = '$contrasena'");
$usuario = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contrasena = '$contrasena'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($admin) > 0) 
{
    session_start();
 
    $_SESSION['admin']="$usuario";

    header("Location: admin/admin.php");
 
    exit(); 
}
 
else if(mysqli_num_rows($usuario) > 0) 
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario']="$usuario";
    header("Location: usuarios/usuarios.php");
    exit(); 
}
 
else 
{
   $mensajeaccesoincorrecto = "El usuario y la contraseña son incorrectos, por favor vuelva a introducirlos.";
   echo $mensajeaccesoincorrecto; 
}
?>
```

Comment: disculpa @BetaM pero sigo sin intender, a que te refieres?

Comment: borre el comentario porque ya logre solucionar, muchas gracias amigo, muy útil tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

La advertencia: *`mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in ...`* significa literalmente que **`mysqli_num_rows()` esperaba como primer parámetro un objeto del tipo `mysqli_result`, pero en cambio, lo que está recibiendo es un objeto nulo**.

En términos de depuración tendrías que revisar la línea donde usas `mysqli_num_rows()` y que te viene indicada en el mensaje de error, verificando allí el objeto que estás pasando a `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Si es esta línea por ejemplo:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($admin) > 0)
```

Y/o bien esta:

```
else if(mysqli_num_rows($usuario) > 0)
```

Significa que **`$admin` y/o  `$usuario` no son objetos `mysqli_result`, sino que son `null`**.  ¿Por qué son `null`? Pues hay que revisar donde se crean esos objetos:

```
$admin = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contrasena = '$contrasena'");
$usuario = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contrasena = '$contrasena'");
```

El **error** es evidente en ambos: **estás usando mal `mysqli_query()`**. Si [revisas la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php), verás que dicha función necesita **dos parámetros**: el primero es la conexión, el segundo es la consulta SQL. Tú no estás pasando la conexión, por eso `$admin` y `$usuario` serán `null`.

### Solución

Pasar la conexión en primer parámetro, aquí imaginamos que la conexión se llama `$mysqli`, si se llama de otro modo lo cambias:

```
$admin = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contrasena = '$contrasena'");
$usuario = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contrasena = '$contrasena'");
```

### Advertencia sobre la seguridad

Tus dos consultas son altamente vulnerables a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Significa que un usuario mal intencionado, con ciertos conocimientos, podría programar código muy dañino e insertarlo en tu sistema a través de la ejecución de esas consultas. El nivel de ataque puede ir desde borrar/obtener/modificar datos sensibles en la base de datos, hasta introducir scripts maliciosos, troyanos, etc en tu sistema de archivos.

Comment: Alguna guía de como aumentar la seguridad al respecto de inyecciones sql ?? o como identificar fallas ?? yo tampoco se de ello.

Comment: @Excorpion aquí mismo hay [varias preguntas/respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+inyección+sql) sobre el tema.

Comment: @Excorpion es un tema bastante amplio, mira por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/245643/29967) que lo aborda también desde otro punto de vista. Allí hay un enlace a OWASP que trata el tema de la seguridad de una forma completa, en diferentes niveles.

Comment: Gracias por la guía ;)

Comment: Un pequeño aporte a la gran explicación de A.Cedano: mysqli_query también puede devolver un null si la SQL es errónea(no solo porque falte un parámetro). Por lo demás, como siempre grandes tus respuestas. 

Comment: Gracias @Jakala, aunque me parece que cuando la consulta falla por error de sintaxis lo que devuelve es `false` y el mensaje en ese caso sería *`... expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`*, de hecho, es el más frecuente, también en varias preguntas aquí. El caso de `null` es raro, pero al fin y al cabo el problema es el mismo: un problema en la ejecución de `mysqli_query()`.