# ¿Mis sentencias preparadas estan bien formuladas o hay algun fallo donde puedan hacer inyeccion SQL?

Tags: php, inyección-sql

```php
static public function CrearNotaModel($tablaBD, $datosController) {
    $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tablaBD(id_paciente, fecha, nota, imc, glucosa, peso)
    VALUES (:id_paciente, :fecha, :nota, :imc, :glucosa, :peso)");

    $pdo -> bindParam(":id_paciente", $datosController["id_paciente"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":fecha", $datosController["fecha"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":nota", $datosController["nota"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":imc", $datosController["imc"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":glucosa", $datosController["glucosa"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":peso", $datosController["peso"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($pdo -> execute()) {
      return true;
    }

    $pdo -> close();
    $pdo = null;

  }
```

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [Inyección SQL en consultas preparadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/245613/29967).

Comment: A primera vista no nay ningún riesgo de *Inyección SQL* en este código (aunque en PDO te pueden emular una consulta preparada e inyectarte código -[ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967)-). Por cierto, esto es redundante: `$pdo -> close(); $pdo = null;` Con uno bastaría. Yo particularmente prefiero el último (no recuerdo ahora si en PDO o mysqli, pero en un escenario, usando `close()` hacía luego `var_dump` del objeto y seguían apareciendo cosas sobre él, mientras que con `null` no ... desde entonces, prefiero `null`).

Comment: Hay un riesgo muy alto y claro de inyección en el ejemplo a través de `$tablaBD` ya que está siendo interpolada. Obviamente las tablas no se pueden pasar en el binding por lo que deberías buscar una forma segura de garantizar que el valor de `$tablaBD` es solo uno de los permitidos.

Answer (score 2):

Las sentencias preparadas son seguras en general si estan contienen interpolaciones de valores directos con `bindParam()` como en el ejemplo de la pregunta.
Esto significa que la consulta ejecutaria correctamente en la mayoria de los casos, excepto por errores de programacion que podrian inducir errores (pero no inyeccion) tales como:

- Strings mas largos de lo que permite el esquema de base de datos (por ejemplo en un varchar(50) no se guardaran mas de 50 caracteres.
- Uso del tipo incorrecto o un valor no esperado en bindParam() (por ejemplo, usar PARAM_STR donde el campo es de tipo entero y el valor no es numerico)

Los problemas de inyeccion pueden venir despues a nivel de despliegue en HTML, si los datos que entran en la base de datos se muestran sin escape (ejemplo, sin usar `htmlentities()` o `htmlspecialchars()`) lo que podria producir inyeccion de codigo externo (XSS) al incrustarlo en el sitio ya sea en contenido HTML como en atributos.

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#xss-prevention-rules-summary